# Empty canvas toDataURL() gets black

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an empty canvas, if I render it as jpeg with quality 0.5 the jpeg will be black, why?

my code:

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', '0.5');
```

Comment: As to WHY: the canvas consist of pixels all set to 0. As the canvas also is initially transparent you won't see these. JPEG does not support transparency so therefor you'll get a black image contrary to using PNG which do support transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll find that the jpeg will be black at any quality. If you want it to be white, you'll have to explicitly fill the canvas with white first. Or, you can encode as PNG.